# how to add cls in tabPanel items

Tags: extjs

4 . a have a tabPanel which contain two items,and one items contains multiple items means app42Tabs function contaion another tabPanel with multiple items. i want to add cls proterty on items app42Tabs.

```
var tabPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
            activeTab: 0,
            id:"tabPanelDB",
            plain:true,
            defaults:{
                autoScroll: true
            },

            items:[{
                title: 'App42 API',
                id:'cloudApiTab',
                layout:'fit',
                items:[app42Tabs()]

            },{
                title: 'AppWarp',
                 id:'cloudApiTab',
            }]
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-cfg-itemCls), you would need to add a `cls` or `itemCls` (depending on which you are trying to override the css) config to the referenced code that is requested when `app42Tabs()` method is executed

Example tab.panel with the config required:

```
var tabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    cls:'myCustomClass',
    itemCls:'anotherCustomClass',
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Tab 1',
            html : 'A simple tab'
        },
        {
            title: 'Tab 2',
            html : 'Another one'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: thanks for response  butif i am add cls class in app42Tabs function means class in another tabs its apply on tabs of app42Tabs but i want to add cls in first tab items

Comment: @naresh, i'm not sure i 100% understand, do you want to modify the existing tabs `cls` when the `app42Tabs()` `render`?

Comment: generally when we are add items in a tabPanel we are writing the syntax this: items:[  {
            title: 'Tab 1',
            html : 'A simple tab',
   cls:'testCls'
        }]
but in my case i have add afunction in items so if i can add cls property this
items:[{
app42Tabs(),
cls:'testForCls'
}] its gives synatex error so please tell me how can i write this 
thanks a lot